# SOAP through C++ Builder

Tags: c++, web-services, soap, wsdl, c++builder

I'm trying to consume my SOAP web service in my **C++** programm. I'm using in-build wizard to generate interaction code automaticaly using my wsdl. When I call non parameterized method everything is OK, but when I trying to call web method with parameter, I get error linked with namespace. I think I need to override `onBeforeExecute` method of `HTTPRIO` to replace some bad tags, but I could not find any useful HTTPRIO documentation or examples wrote on **C++**. Can anybody give me a link dedicated to HTTPRIO applying with SOAP. Or may be someone already faced with transmitting parameters problem and knows more elegant solution?

```
Unmarshaling error: unexpected element(uri:"/*my_service_namespace*/", local:"/*parameter_name*/"). Expected element are <{}/*parameter_name*/>
```

Comment: we might be able to help you if you provide some of the code and the errors you're getting.

Comment: Actually, don't see the need in my code here.

Comment: ofc not your whole code but the part that your debugger is mentioning

Comment: Wherein the error code is in virtual function which body generates by wizard and I cannot get a text of it's body, thats why I cannot put breakpoint to it.

Comment: In the generated code is a line starting with something like: InvRegistry()->RegisterInvokeOptions it might help to test some different options or to remove the line completely.